# FastCGI apache mod making HTTPS fail

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, ssl, fastcgi

We hired somebody last month to install FastCGI in place of suphp, so that we could install magento multisites on our server. We have monitors set to watch some of our websites on siteuptime.com, and the monitors are coming back saying HTTPS randomly fails and then comes back up within minutes. On occasion, HTTP also fails and comes back up within minutes. Any ideas which variable i need to change within fastcgi to fix this problem?

Comment: im asking you guys

Comment: the person was hired with a contract to come in and do it. im the server admin normally. now that their job is over, its my responsibility to maintain fastcgi. i need to know which settings need to be changed to fix the problem. any ideas?